# String manipulation in google spreadsheet for getting city name and states from address

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am working on a google spreadsheet and I was stuck how to extract the second state name from the string.

## MWE

```
A                    B     C        D
1 Address           City   State1  State2
2 Dublin,OH         Dublin OH
3 Chicago,IL,NY     Chicago IL     NY
4 NY,Atlanta, DC    Atlanta NY     DC
5 Seattle,WA        Seattle WA


From the address, how to get city, state1, and state2?
```

Link to the google sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10NzbtJhQj4hQBnZXcmwise3bLBIAWrE0qwSus_bz7a0/edit?usp=sharing

Notes

- The state name is all caps.
- There can be no second state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the spreadsheet you shared I entered in B1

```
={"City", "State1", "State2"; Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), split(A2:A, ","),))}
```

See if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose "Dublin, OH" from your post example list were in A2 with the others running from A3:A. Try this in B2 (making sure that B2:B is blank first):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IF(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"[A-Z]{2}")=REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+([A-Z]{2})$"),TRUE),,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+([A-Z]{2})$")))))`

The "plain-English version" of this reads as follows:

"If any cell in A2:A is blank, the corresponding cell in B2:B should also be blank. Otherwise, if the first instance of two juxtaposed capital letters is the same as the last instance of two juxtaposed capital letters, there is only one state present: leave that cell in Col B blank. Otherwise, pull the last such instance. If there are no instances of two juxtaposed capital letters for any test, instead of listing it as an error, list that as blank also."

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I tried this formula in cell B2, but it gives me empty output.

Comment: It works in my sheet with the exact data shown in your post. If you'd like to share a link to your sample spreadsheet, I will be happy to take a look for you. Be sure to set the link's Share permission (when you create the link) to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor."

Comment: See the screenshot I just added to my post, where you see the formula in B2 and the correct results underneath.

Comment: I tried the formula given, and replaced {2} by {1} for the state1 to get the first state but I got some problems. Would you share some light on getting city, state1, state2 on the public link shared. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your original post before you edited said you wanted to extract only the last state listed. It seems you've changed what you want. It also seems that you've said the solution offered by JPV meets your needs. So I am left confused as to what you are asking. Is this issue now solved?

Comment: Erik, I started with a simple breaking string into city and state but later I realized that my problem was harder than simple text extraction and updated the question. Sorry for XY problem. I still appreciate your effort and upvoted your efforts.

Comment: @ErikTyler if you want to shorten your formula by a colossal 8 characters, I think you can reduce your regix statement to be `"[A-Z]{2}$"` instead of `".+([A-Z]{2})$"` with identical results. The `$` identifies the end of the string so no need to express it before with the `.+`.

Comment: @pgSystemTester, thanks. This is an old post. REGEX is one of those things that gets refined the more you use it, and lots has happened in the nine months since this post. In addition, REGEX (and really *all* formula writing) tend to get more or less concise depending on one's state of mind. I've written formulas in the past while tired that, while they've worked, I've gone back later and thought, "Was I drunk? That could have been a quarter the length!"

Comment: My buddy and I call that *Cringe Code* which is the overwhelming since of dread you see from stuff you built long ago before you know as much as you know now. I have some old posts on here that indeed make me cringe! Regex is a little new to me... too.